# C# Excel Interop: Replace Isn't Replacing values

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using Excel interop to replace all comma values in an Excel workbook, and then saving the obtained file as a csv. I'm doing this as follows:

```
            var app = new Application();
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(excelfilename);
            Worksheet sheet = wb.WorkSheets[0];
            sheet.Activate();
            Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            Range range = sheet.Range["A1", last];

            int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
            int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
            var startcell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
            var endcell = sheet.Cells[lastUsedRow, lastUsedColumn];
            var subrange = sheet.Range[startcell, endcell];

            subrange.Replace(@",", @"", XlLookAt.xlPart, XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, false, Type.Missing, false, false);
            wb.SaveAs(outputfilename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
            wb.Close(false, "", true);
```

However, I found that the above code doesn't actually replace all the commas in the sheet, and I still have commas in the Worksheet before I export to CSV. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cant you change the culture here? Seems thats what you are trying todo?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? In essence I'm simply looking to convert an Excel worksheet to CSV (which will finally be imported into SQL Server using BULK INSERT). I'm replacing all the commas in the field, as that's what I'm using as field delimiter. If I use a different delimiter, I'd have to check whether that delimiter is in any cell value in any case.